# Ajax post return 400 error, when move the code out of the project folder - Codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

(Project is in localhost)
I have an ajax function that fetch some data from Model class via controller and the url code is url: "User/display_details".

I have moved the entire project code into another folder and in 'config.php' i have updated the base_url.

But when I load page, ajax function return 404 error, that is the function is unable to post the request into the 'User Controller' anymore.

(I want to achieve that, when user type http://localhost , the my webapp should show up other than typing http://localhost/projectname. So I moved entire code out of the project folder)

Comment: also post your code?

Comment: What url does your ajax call? Probably your ajax call url could be wrong, where `base_url` nothing to do with on the front end.